# AIR 3rd party dependency required to have universal iOS libraries

Tags: ios, air, flash-builder, distriqt

Not much of an iOS developer here, but we are unable to build using Flash Builder.

The message clearly points out to a 3rd party library dependency called **com.distriqt.PushNotifications**, but we are not sure how to investigate the problem, or what to ask from the 3rd party vendor.

```
Error: libPushNotifications.a are required to have universal iOS libraries. Please contact the ANE developer(s) to get the same.
```

We don't know what "universal iOS libraries" actually mean, and we think that the error started after Xcode upate from 5 to 7.

We are looking forward for any checklist or examination that could help us fix this problem and generate package the application.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might have an old version of the ANE.

http://airnativeextensions.com/extension/com.distriqt.PushNotifications

or contact the developers at airnativeextensions@distriqt.com

Comment: This is most definitely an old ANE. All our ANE's were updated to universal libraries on iOS over a year ago.

Comment: We needed to update the library that is compatible with the new xcode.